# VB.NET: Using a Type argument vs using a Generic Function?

Tags: vb.net, generics, types

I am unsure what the difference is between using a generic function using `(Of T)`, and using a type parameter `returnType As Type`, nor what the best approach would be for a function that converts a JSON String to an Object subtype as illustrated below.

Visual Studio complains when I try to access properties of an object whose subtype I know beforehand, as well as when trying to cast the object to the desired subtype. However, it only does this when using the generic function approach.

I need the functions signature to be generic enough so that it can be included in an interface for multiple classes to later implement.

```
Public Overloads Function Execute(jsonData As String, returnType As Type) As Object Implements IHandler.Execute

    ' Deserializes the JSON to the specified .NET type.
    Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData, returnType)

    ' Visual Studio does not complain, and the function still works 
    ' without the need of explicitly converting and checking:

    ' result = TryCast(result, Response)

    ' If result Is Nothing Then
    '    Throw New Exception("Conversion failed")
    ' End If

    ' Visual Studio does not complain:
    if result.Success Then
        ProcessMessage(result.Message)
    ElseIf result.Errors.length > 0 Then
        HandleErrors(result.Errors)
    End If

    Return result

End Function


Public Overloads Function Execute(Of T)(jsonData As String) As T Implements IHandler.Execute

    ' Deserializes the JSON to the specified .NET type.
    Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(jsonData)

    ' Visual Studio complains:
    result = TryCast(result, Response)

    If result Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("Conversion failed")
    End If

    ' Visual Studio complains:
    if result.Success Then
        ProcessMessage(result.Message)
    ElseIf result.Errors.length > 0 Then
        HandleErrors(result.Errors)
    End If

    Return result

End Function
```

What is the best approach, what is the difference between the two, and why does Visual Studio complain when using the generic approach but does not complain when passing the type as an argument?

I am using the `JsonConvert` class from the `Newtonsoft.Json` framework.

Reference: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: In the generic function: what is dataResult? You are deserializing an object, but aren't actually using it as you overwrite result with a conversion of (the unknown?) dataresult.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg It was a none critical mistake. It should have been "result" but sadly that isn't to do with the solution. I added that part of the code later on to try and highlight the problem further and just typed it incorrectly. Thank you for noticing it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why the compiler complains about the generic function, but it has nothing to do with being generic.

First of all, the result variable is of type T:

```
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(jsonData)
```

I don't think `result.Success` and `result.Errors` are defined in T. So it is obvious the compiler complains about that. *If you want to use these functions, then don't use T but Response instead.*

Also you are trying to cast the variable result to Response (which is of type T):

```
result = TryCast(result, Response)
```

You cannot cast result to type Response as result is of type T. Then it should be:

```
result = TryCast(result, T)
```

But you don't need this statement at all since result already is the casted to T.

In general: don't use Object if you don't have to. Use generic functions. Always use the most specific type.

Call the function with the specified type: Execute(Of Response)(jsonData) or change the function to:

```
Public Overloads Function Execute(jsonData As String) As Response Implements IHandler.Execute
    Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Response)(jsonData)
```

Comment: I definitely need to make the function generic or declare the type being used. But using `Execute(Of Response)(jsonData)` does not work because the body of code I need to write (from a class which implements the generic function) relies on a specific type, which is why I need to cast it to the correct type.

I'm just unsure why one method works but the other does not.

Comment: You could use an interface. Cast the result as the interface which has the properties you need.

Comment: I do not have time to give an example right now. I will try to update my answer later today.

Comment: Thank you. I was mainly concerned with why specifying the type as an argument works, whereas specifying the type as a generic type parameter does not.